# Android Button and ImageButton method

Tags: java, android, button, imagebutton

There is any particular way to use Button or imageButton with every Android version ? The code I used to create a Button(I also used an ImageButton) give me crash problem with the emulator of Nexus 5 and Samsung S4 while in Samsung Galaxy Ace it works! The code I used :

```
MyBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("Clicked", " ! ");
        }
    });
```

I also used the xml way but with android:onClick="" seems that Android Studio can't find the method DoThis(View v) and so it crashes. Any suggestion?

MainActivity :

package teateam.wimeet;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String Friends = new String();
    private ImageButton MyBut;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyBut = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.button1);
        MyBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Clicked!", "");
            }
        });    
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

logcat :

```
02-21 20:01:17.085    2323-2323/testing.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: testing.test, PID: 2323
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{testing.test/testing.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at testing.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You haven't given us enough to go on. The problem is clearly a NullPointerException at line 27 of your onCreate(...) method. Post your MainActivity code.

Comment: @Squonk line 27 is MyBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         I didn't add anything in the code after created the project, only the lines I posted, and obvius the declaration of MyBut as ImageButton

Comment: @ClearCode How are you defining `MyBut` and does the id exists ? Can you also check if the layout file in the `setContentView` has that id ?

Comment: OK, so MyBut is clearly null. As I said, edit your question to show your MainActivity code.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri private ImageButton MyBut;

Comment: The strange thing is that the code works in my Samsung Galaxy Ace (S7500) and not in my Samsung Galaxy S4

Comment: @ClearCode : Do you have multiple `activity_main.xml` layout files in different /res/layout directories?

Comment: @Squonk No, it seems that a lot of people has this problem..

Comment: @ClearCode : That doesn't make sense. The only way `MyBut` can be null is if the `findViewById` method in `MyBut = (ImageButton) findViewById( R.id.button1);` is unable to find an `ImageButton` with the id `@+id/button1` in the current content view.